# Need Help combining to android projects into one

Tags: android

Hi I have 2 android projects in eclipse a subnet calculator and a data tester The problem is that they are in two different projects! I want to add the data tester one into the subnet calculator! The question is how do I do this?

I have tried almost everything I can think of!!

Please help!!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: simple copy all activity class in main Project &  change Manifest As per Add Activity also Add Layout of it

Comment: Make one a Library and import it to the other.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this what you need to do is.

1. Create a new project.
2. Create some sort of navigation.
3. Copy your class files and layouts to the new project's respective directories updating references.
4. Declare each of your activity in manifest along with permissions used by both apps.